Dynamic Configuration of Facebook Login with react-native-fbsdk-next in Expo
I am using react-native-fbsdk-next with Expo to implement Facebook login. In order to configure this, I need to include certain settings in app.config.ts, as shown in the image below:

However, I want to avoid hardcoding these values directly in the configuration file. Instead of using environment variables, I would like to fetch these configurations dynamically from an API, allowing me to update them whenever necessary. Since app.config.ts is generated only at build time, is there a way to pass these configurations dynamically?
I came across a potential solution
  const setFBSDKSecrets = async () => {
      const res: SSOType = await API('/auth/get-credentials', {
        method: 'GET',
      })

      Settings.setAppID(res.facebook.clientId)
      Settings.setClientToken(res.facebook.clientToken)
      Settings.setAppName('myApp')
      Settings.setAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled(false)
      Settings.setAutoLogAppEventsEnabled(false)
    }

    setFBSDKSecrets()

I implemented this by adding the settings there and removing them from app.config.ts. However, when I ran yarn start, I encountered an error stating that the appID is missing:
Error: missing appID in the plugin properties

Can anyone provide solution on how to resolve this issue or suggest a better approach for dynamically configuring Facebook login settings in Expo?
